# Ubuntu 15.10 freezes, shut down, suspend, restart doesn´t work (ACER Aspire E-15 Start)

Tags: boot, grub2, suspend, shutdown, 15.10

I am using ubuntu 15.10 and I am unable to shut down, restart, suspend, although logging off/on works. 
I have tried to update the grub with this command: sudo grub-update then my ubuntu system can't recognize the grub-update.

I have also tried this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
$ sudo apt-get install unity
$ setsid unity
```

I have also tried from other comment, to change in BIOS from legacy to UEFI - but then my system just can't recognize that I have ubuntu system installed. I am using ACER Aspire E 15 start.

The issue is that I couldn't reboot or shut down. When I press ESC it says

Reached shut down
And it freezes on this place.

Also I have further information, cause it started to freeze at random time. My first suspect is cron.daily that does something to google chrome, but still not sure what. Anyhow I am not sure if this is connected to my shut-down, suspend, restart problem.

Does anyone has any other ideas how to solve the issue ? 
If you need anymore information, ask me ?

Comment: Unlikely that a cron job is to blame. However you can find out what the cron jobs at play are by doing crontab -e and also do sudo crontab -e on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue (shutdown did not turn the notebook off) with my ACER E15

I read that the problem was related to usb (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.p...4#post12389814)

I solved it by disabling xHCI support (usb3 related support) on the BIOS and now it shuts down fine

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my hard disk, because of this annoying task. I am using SSD now and everything works out. Maybe this is not a solution to my problem, but I would say that this is a workaround. 
Also I have already posted in the comments above I have changed I have change inside BIOS from legacy to UEFI.